# Export from PHP to CSV without the header and footer

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, csv, export

I'm using a template in my website, so when I export from PHP to CSV using Javascript :

> window.location ="index.php/exporter_resultats";

I get a CSV file full of html of the whole page, not just the data I need.

Is there a way I can export the content of a specific div of the page, without the header and footer and the rest?

Comment: you can parse html with regex and take what you need.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541926/best-way-to-execute-a-javascript-and-php-csv-export-script might help

Answer (score 0):

You can get the contents of a specific div or element using jquery and then parse that using js.
In your html:

```
<div id="myDiv">I just want this text</div>
```

In your js:

```
var divContent = $("#myDiv").html();
```

This will at least get you the specific conten to parse instead of the entire page.

Hope that helps.