# Php report generation

Tags: php, excel, pdf

I would like to generate report from my php which now I have only the html version. Can any one suggest me good tools to generate excel and pdf based tool at minimum? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for excel you can generate .csv file

try this one

[Create a CSV File for a user in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217424/create-a-csv-file-for-a-user-in-php)

and for PDF read this

http://www.sitepoint.com/generate-pdfs-php/

Comment: Is csv equal to excel? So we do not need extra library for the excel to be installed is it?

Comment: csv is good for excel its works fine create one thru excel and you will get it (p.s. csv = comma separated values)

Comment: if it is just a csv file how will be a .xls file then? How to come out with the columns etc?

Comment: see this page and it will be brighter for you
https://admin.easymail.rmplc.co.uk/admin_help/csv.htm

Comment: if say I have my columns and rows set with color on the html then how to transfer into .csv?

Comment: you can also create a simple html table (<tr><td></td></tr>) and excel will load it

Answer (score 0):

you can use birt-viewer reports tool generate the reports to any lanuage php/java and its open source

http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/

Comment: I went to the site but I dont see any relevance to pdf or excel?

Comment: when u create report it can export to what u want format pdf excel csv etc

Comment: How will this birt component help in php programming as it is built for java environment right?

Comment: yes you need to  install tomcat server to birt run read the installation guide in your php web application you can give URL path to the reports then user can click and on that load the reports reports loading from tomcat server

Comment: the installation guide is more for windows how about linux? so it can support what format reports?