# Using php to export a mysql query to a downloadable .csv file

Tags: php, mysql, csv, export, download

I've tried my darnest to avoid asking this question (I viewed and try a ton of examples already on the forum), most partially work which leads me to believe I'm missing something. I have a link setup to export my table into a downloadable .csv file. When I click the link the code dumps the table in csv format, BUT instead of it loading as an attachment it just displays the contents of the table in html.

--

```
<?php

include('bikes.php');    //db connection settings
if ($_GET['action'] == 'download')
{
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.csv"');

$query = "SELECT * FROM bikes";

$export = mysql_query ($query ) or die ( "Sql error : " . mysql_error( ) );

$fields = mysql_num_fields ( $export );

for ( $i = 0; $i < $fields; $i++ )
{
    $header .= mysql_field_name( $export , $i ) . "\t";
}

while( $row = mysql_fetch_row( $export ) )
{
    $line = '';
    foreach( $row as $value )
    {                                            
        if ( ( !isset( $value ) ) || ( $value == "" ) )
        {
            $value = "\t";
        }
        else
        {
            $value = str_replace( '"' , '""' , $value );
            $value = '"' . $value . '"' . "\t";
        }
        $line .= $value;
    }
    $data .= trim( $line ) . "\n";
}
$data = str_replace( "\r" , "" , $data );

if ( $data == "" )
{
    $data = "\n(0) Records Found!\n";                        
}

print "$header\n$data";

}
exit();

php?>
```

--

My results how up as

A, B, C, D, A, B, C, D -- I have no idea why when I click my link (download.php?action=download) that is does not prompt me to save the file to my hard drive, instead of just displaying the information on the page.

Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: So...I figured out why out of the 20+ examples I tried I could not get the download to work. Apparently you have to have a blank php file. Meaning there should only be php code and no html. As soon as I did that all the header features worked w/o a problem. Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use before sending the output:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.csv"');
```

See: [Create a CSV File for a user in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217424/create-a-csv-file-for-a-user-in-php) - For more details.

Comment: Just tried using the headerline but i'm still getting the same result. :\

Comment: @snapplex Read the edit (added a link to another question already asked)

Comment: Side note: I feel like a mook.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, works for me:

```
header("Content-Type: text/csv");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0,pre-check=0");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\n");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.csv"');
```