# Convert MySQL table (utf8 data) to Excel file

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, export

I'm trying to export an MySQL table into an xls file.
The issue is that the table data is in hebrew and saved as utf8.
for some reason when I export the file, the text is not readable by excel.

The table is utf8.

```
function export_excel_csv($DB_TBLName)
{

global $connectionion;
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");   
$sql = "select * from {$DB_TBLName}";

//Optional: print out title to top of Excel or Word file with Timestamp
//for when file was generated:
//set $Use_Titel = 1 to generate title, 0 not to use title
$Use_Title = 1;
//define date for title: EDIT this to create the time-format you need
$now_date = DATE('m-d-Y H:i');
//define title for .doc or .xls file: EDIT this if you want
$title = "Dump For Table $DB_TBLName from Database $DB_TBLName on $now_date";


//execute query
$result = MYSQL_QUERY($sql,$connectionion)
     or DIE("Couldn't execute query:<br>" . MYSQL_ERROR(). "<br>" . MYSQL_ERRNO());

//if this parameter is included ($w=1), file returned will be in word format ('.doc')
//if parameter is not included, file returned will be in excel format ('.xls')
IF (ISSET($w) && ($w==1))
{
     $file_type = "msword";
     $file_ending = "doc";
}ELSE {
     $file_type = "application/csv";
     $file_ending = "csv";
}
//header info for browser: determines file type ('.doc' or '.xls')
HEADER("Content-Type: application/$file_type; charset='UTF-8';");
HEADER("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=database_dump.$file_ending");
HEADER("Pragma: no-cache");
HEADER("Expires: 0");

/*    Start of Formatting for Word or Excel    */

IF (ISSET($w) && ($w==1)) //check for $w again
{
     /*    FORMATTING FOR WORD DOCUMENTS ('.doc')   */
     //create title with timestamp:
     IF ($Use_Title == 1)
     {
         ECHO("$title\n\n");
     }
     //define separator (defines columns in excel & tabs in word)
     $sep = "\n"; //new line character

     WHILE($row = MYSQL_FETCH_ROW($result))
     {
         //set_time_limit(60); // HaRa
         $schema_insert = "";
         FOR($j=0; $j<mysql_num_fields($result);$j++)
         {
         //define field names
         $field_name = MYSQL_FIELD_NAME($result,$j);
         //will show name of fields
         $schema_insert .= "$field_name:\t";
             IF(!ISSET($row[$j])) {
                 $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
                 }
             ELSEIF ($row[$j] != "") {
                 $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
                 }
             ELSE {
                 $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
                 }
         }
         $schema_insert = STR_REPLACE($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
         $schema_insert .= "\t";
         PRINT(TRIM($schema_insert));
         //end of each mysql row
         //creates line to separate data from each MySQL table row
         PRINT "\n----------------------------------------------------\n";
     }
}ELSE{
     /*    FORMATTING FOR EXCEL DOCUMENTS ('.xls')   */
     //create title with timestamp:
     IF ($Use_Title == 1)
     {
         ECHO("$title\n");
     }
     //define separator (defines columns in excel & tabs in word)
     $sep = "\t"; //tabbed character

     //start of printing column names as names of MySQL fields
     FOR ($i = 0; $i < MYSQL_NUM_FIELDS($result); $i++)
     {
         ECHO MYSQL_FIELD_NAME($result,$i) . "\t";
     }
     PRINT("\n");
     //end of printing column names

     //start while loop to get data
     WHILE($row = MYSQL_FETCH_ROW($result))
     {
         //set_time_limit(60); // HaRa
         $schema_insert = "";
         FOR($j=0; $j<mysql_num_fields($result);$j++)
         {
             IF(!ISSET($row[$j]))
                 $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
             ELSEIF ($row[$j] != "")
                 $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
             ELSE
                 $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
         }
         $schema_insert = STR_REPLACE($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
         //following fix suggested by Josue (thanks, Josue!)
         //this corrects output in excel when table fields contain \n or \r
         //these two characters are now replaced with a space
         $schema_insert = PREG_REPLACE("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
         $schema_insert .= "\t";
         PRINT(TRIM($schema_insert));
         PRINT "\n";
     }
```

If someone has an idea what I'm doing wrong, I'll be glad to know :)
Cheers,
Sagi.

Comment: Plus the heading is screwballed... application/$file_type when $file_type is application/csv gives application/application/csv

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually saving as an Excel (.xls or .xlsx) file, you're saving as a CSV file with a tab rather than a comma separator (which is a file format that Excel is capable of reading)... but just because you're sending a header to the browser to tell it that the content is UTF-8, doesn't mean that Excel will be aware of this when you open the file in MS Excel.

If you want UTF-8 data when you open this file in Excel, then either write a genuine Excel (.xls or .xlsx) file (depending on the version of Excel you're targetting).
Or, try writing a BOM marker to your CSV file (no guarantees).

Comment: I'm not sure how am I spouse to write a genuine Excel file. basically I need to find a way to export that data into a readable excel file which is utf8.

Comment: There's dozens of libraries available for PHP that will write Excel files - I'm the author of one.... but you can find a comprehensive list of options here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930975/alternative-for-php-excel or google for PHP and Excel

Answer (score 0):

This is not an XLS file, but CSV, use this header:

```
header("Content-type: application/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
```

Also check this topic:
[Create a CSV File for a user in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217424/create-a-csv-file-for-a-user-in-php)

If that still causes problems we can look further