# Add Column Headers To a CSV File With PHP

Tags: php, csv

I am trying to convert a php/mysql generated table into a downloadable csv file.  When a user enters search parameters, a call is made to a mysql table and results returned as table.

I used the solution offered in this thread and it works fabulously:     [Create a CSV File for a user in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217424/create-a-csv-file-for-a-user-in-php)

I am able to allow users to save or view the results as a csv file.  the problem I am having is I'm not sure how to add column headers to the file.  For example, the results that are returned are in the following format:  $result[x]['office'], $result[x]['user'], etc..., but I also want to add column titles like "Office" and "User" so that anyone looking at the csv file immediately knows what the data means.

This is the function that generates the csv file:

```
    header("Content-type: text/csv");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file.csv");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");
    outputCSV($data);

function outputCSV($data) {
        $outstream = fopen("php://output", "a");
        function __outputCSV(&$vals, $key, $filehandler) {
            fputcsv($filehandler, $vals); // add parameters if you want
        }
        array_walk($data, "__outputCSV", $outstream);
        fclose($outstream);
    }
```

I have tried creating the following function, and then calling it right before I call outputCSV, but it is not successful:

```
function create_file_header()
{       
    $headers = 'Office, User, Tag, Value';
    $fp = fopen("php://output", "w");
    file_put_contents("$file.csv", $headers);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Open the file in 'w' mode http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To create headers, you should just prepend a header row array and use `fputcsv` as normal.

You don't talk about the format of `$data`, but if it's an associative array you can do this for a generic solution:

```php
function toCSV($data, $outstream) {
    if (count($data)) {
        // get header from keys
        fputcsv($outstream, array_keys($data[0]));
        // 
        foreach ($data as $row) {
            fputcsv($outstream, $row);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm don't see the benefit of `array_walk()` over a `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 2):

Do this before calling outputCSV:

```
array_unshift($data, array('Office', 'User', 'Tag', 'Value'));
```

Or, if the elements of `$data` are associative arrays, this would be more dynamic:

```
array_unshift($data, array_keys($data[0]));
```

Comment: This is a genius solution!  I ended up using `array_push()` in a slightly different case, but this is perfect for someone getting the header columns in MySQL by using `fetch_fields()` and then appending more fields to them.  Kudos.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just put it in the outputCSV function?

```
header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file.csv");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
outputCSV($data);

function outputCSV($data) {
    $outstream = fopen("php://output", "a");

    $headers = 'Office, User, Tag, Value';
    fwrite($outstream,$headers);

    function __outputCSV(&$vals, $key, $filehandler) {
        fputcsv($filehandler, $vals); // add parameters if you want
    }
    array_walk($data, "__outputCSV", $outstream);
    fclose($outstream);
 }
```

Comment: Just a note.  In my experience, I needed to add `."\r\n"` at the end of `$headers = 'Office, User, Tag, Value'` line, i.e. `$headers = 'Office, User, Tag, Value'."\r\n"` or the first row would be appended to the header row without line break.

Answer (score 0):

Add an optional `$headers` parameter to your `outputCSV` function. If your code passes them, they will be prepended to the csv array:

```
outputCSV($data, array('Office', 'User'));

//

function outputCSV($data, $headers = null) {
    $outstream = fopen("php://output", "a");
    function __outputCSV(&$vals, $key, $filehandler) {
        fputcsv($filehandler, $vals); // add parameters if you want
    }
    if ($headers) {
        $data = array_merge(array($headers), $data);
    }
    array_walk($data, "__outputCSV", $outstream);
    fclose($outstream);
}
```