# PHP - Can I apply custom font styles to the header of a CSV file?

Tags: php, csv

Is that a way to custom the header of a generated csv file :

```
$result = $db->select(" table","",""," fitstname, lastname, campany");
$headers = array("fistname","lastname","campany"); 
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w'); 

if ($fp && $result) {     
    header('Content-Type: text/csv ; charset=utf-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="recap.csv"');
    header('Pragma: no-cache');    
    header('Expires: 0');

    fputcsv($fp, $headers); 
    for ($i= 0; $i < sizeof($result); $i++) {
        fputcsv($fp, array_values($result[$i])); 
    }
    die; 
}
```

**updated :**
here the output :

```
nom,prenom,societe
Charles,Olivier,"Zed way"
Bernard,Gautier,"Media Productions"
```

Regards .

Comment: Can you post a sample ouput CSV file?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9298264/add-column-headers-to-a-csv-file-with-php?rq=1

Comment: it doesn't answer my question , it's about adding header ... for me i can add header but i'm enable to custom it ( color , bold , font )

Comment: You can't style csv file

Answer (score 1):

On php.net you can find helpfull user comments to nearly every
(un)documented function and feature.
This answers your question very well.. >>
[php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php#104980](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php#104980)

## Update:

Well as you can read in the first line, when hit the link above, it's sufficient to do this:

```
<?php $out = fopen('php://output', 'w');fputcsv($out, array('this','is some', 'csv "stuff", you know.'));fclose($out); ?>
```

This will directly output your csv in the browser window...
If you wnat to make the browser handling it as a download, then you must do the header-things... What is it you want to do?

Comment: i can't find the answer , can you be more precis ?? plz

Comment: well lets seeeee.. i'll add somewhat to my prev answer

Comment: you can change the style of the outputed file, not the header... this then is simple html. csv as is, is plain text - no way to edit styles there....

Comment: ok , thanks,i'll look how to pass from html to the  csv file.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: CSV files contain only data. There's no formatting information, and no structural information beyond field and record delimiters.

The longer answer: You can include formatting and other information if you target the output file to a specific application. Of course, then it ceases to be a CSV file. If you want to output to Excel format you can use a library such as [PHPExcel](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/). There are other libraries that would allow output to PDF, Word, or other application formats, or you could just generate an HTML table.