How import also column name in CSV file
I have this code that works perfectly to export a table to a CSV file, but it does not insert header column name.
<?php

$host = 'host';
$mydatabase = 'db';
$user = 'user';
$pass = 'pass';
try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$mydatabase, $user, $pass);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    die();
}

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id ';

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

if ($output != '') {
    $output .= "\n";
}

while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $output .= '"'.$row['id'].'",';
    $output .= '"'.$row['name'].'",';
    $output .= '"'.$row['surname'].'",';
    $output .= '"'.$row['etc'].'",';
    $output .= "\n";
}

$file = 'table.csv';
$f = fopen($file, 'w');
fwrite($f, $output);
fclose($f);


First thing first, please remove echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage(); and try-catch. Wherever you learned this is wrong.

You don't have any code that would create a CSV header.

Where is $output defined?

True, I tried several way to insert headers, but no one add column name to the file.

Are you asking how to get the column names from PDO? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428262/php-pdo-get-the-columns-name-of-a-table

I saw that question and try it. The line $table_fields = $dbh->query("DESCRIBE tablename")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN); did not work for me. But, actually, I'not sure that the line position was in the right place. Where must I place it in my code?

"did not work" is a meaningless problem description. I am not sure what it means. If it's supposed to be a header then it seems logical that it would be the first thing in your file, so you should put it at the start of your $output string.

Also here is how to create a CSV file https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217424/create-a-csv-file-for-a-user-in-php

Maybe this is what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9298264/add-column-headers-to-a-csv-file-with-php

You don't need to run a DESCRIBE query to get the column names, you're using FETCH_ASSOC so the names are already available as keys in $row, just use array_keys($row) on the first iteration of the loop.

Also, don't build your own CSV with string concatenation, instead use fputcsv() so that quotes and escapes are properly handled.

It depends on what exactly you want.
Assuming that you only want a header if you have some data in the table, you can do it this way:
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id ';

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

$fp = fopen('table.csv', 'w');

$data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if($data !== []) {
    fputcsv($fp, array_keys($data[0]));
    foreach ($data as $row) {
        fputcsv($fp, $row);
    }
}

fclose($fp);

However, most people will tell you that SELECT * is a bad idea. You should list all the columns explicitly. If you can list the columns in SQL then you can also list them in your CSV generation script. Nothing wrong with a little duplication.
If you would like to have a header in your CSV file always even when there are no data rows, then you can just hardcode it.
