# PHP: Download a string as csv file?

Tags: php, download

I have a string which contains csv data. Can I somehow offer that string for download as a csv file without saving it before?

Thanks

Comment: You can find the solution here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217424/create-a-csv-file-for-a-user-in-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
header("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=myfilename.csv");
```

Answer (score 12):

```
<?php
      header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
      header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"my-data.csv\"");
      $data="col1, col start and end col2,col3, \n";
      $data .= "second line data";
      echo $data;
?>
```

Above code will display a window in visitor browser asking to save file in local computer or open by suitable application.

Comment: This should be the top answer. The above did not work for me echoing a csv as a string.