# Exporting html (mysql populated) table to excel file

Tags: php, html, mysql, export-to-excel

I am trying to query a mysql database and display data in a table.  That part is working.  At the moment, it is set up for displaying the
 results within the certain date range.

I now want to take the table and make a button that allows you to export it to an Excel file.  Before I added the option of choosing a date range, you were able to export to Excel, but now it seems that the second file does not know what table I am talking about.  I tried using POST to send the values of the data and re-query on the other page.

When I click the button to export, the excel document that is downloaded is empty, (though it has a size). Any help please?

-----Query mysql---------

```
 <html><head><title>New Production Rejections</title></head></html>
    <?php 

    include("config.php");
    //get serial from submitted data
        //$serial = $_POST['sNumber'];
        //if the submitted data is empty
        $serial = $_POST['entryDate'];
    $dateEnd = $_POST['entryDate2'];
        //parse the serial from the link in tracker
    ?>
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo "queryNewProdRejections.php?"?>">
        Search between dates: (Format: YYYY-MM-DD)<input type='text' size='20' maxlength='20' name='entryDate'> - <input type='text' size='20' maxlength='20' name='entryDate2'>
        <input type="submit" value="Search Date Range"><br/></form>

    <?php


    //query based on approved date that is nothing, repaired date that is nothing, 
    //tech is a real tech, location that is not Revite (RVP), action was to replace, 
    //and the status is not (declined or skipped).

    $query = "SELECT *
    FROM `rma`
    WHERE `origin` NOT LIKE 'Field_failure'
    AND `origin` NOT LIKE 'DOA_at_Customer'
    AND `origin` NOT LIKE 'Sweden_Fail_VI'
    AND `entry` > '$serial' AND `entry` < '$dateEnd'";
    $data = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    //Create a table with the array of data from repairs, based on the previous query

    echo "<table border='1'><tr><th>RMA</th><th>Product</th><th>Serial</th><th>Origin</th><th>Return To</th><th>Credit Num</th><th>Order</th><th>Entry Date</th><th>Tech</th><th>Traking Num</th></tr>";

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($data)){ 
        print "<tr><td>".$row['intrma']."</td><td>".$row['product']."</td><td>".$row['serial']."</td><td>".$row['origin']."</td><td>".$row['retto']."</td><td>".$row['creditnum']."</td><td>".$row['ordernum']."</td><td>".$row['entry']."</td><td>".$row['tech']."</td><td>".$row['tracknum']."</td></tr>";
    }
    print "</table>";

    ?>
    <html>
    <form method="post" action="saveQueryToExcel.php">
    <input type='hidden' name='ent_1' value="<?php echo $_POST['entryDate']; ?>">
    <input type='hidden' name='ent_2' value="<?php echo $_POST['entryDate2']; ?>">
      <input type="submit" value="Save to Excel">
    </form>
    </html>
```

---------------Print to Excel File -- (saveQueryToExcel.php)

```
<html><head><title>New Production Rejections</title></head></html>

<?php
error_reporting(0);

$dateBeg=$_POST['ent_1'];
$dateEnd=$_POST['ent_2'];

//Connect to the database, repairs in maprdweb
include("config.php");

//query based on approved date that is nothing, repaired date that is nothing, 
//tech is a real tech, location that is not Revite (RVP), action was to replace, 
//and the status is not (declined or skipped).

$query = "SELECT *
FROM `rma`
WHERE `origin` NOT LIKE 'Field_failure'
AND `origin` NOT LIKE 'DOA_at_Customer'
AND `origin` NOT LIKE 'Sweden_Fail_VI'
AND `entry` > '$dateBeg' AND `entry` < '$dateEnd'";
$data = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

//Create a table with the array of data from repairs, based on the previous query
header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');

echo "<table border='1'><tr><th>RMA</th><th>Product</th><th>Serial</th><th>Origin</th><th>Return To</th><th>Credit Num</th><th>Order</th><th>Entry Date</th><th>Tech</th><th>Traking Num</th></tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($data)){ 
    print "<tr><td>".$row['intrma']."</td><td>".$row['product']."</td><td>".$row['serial']."</td><td>".$row['origin']."</td><td>".$row['retto']."</td><td>".$row['creditnum']."</td><td>".$row['ordernum']."</td><td>".$row['entry']."</td><td>".$row['tech']."</td><td>".$row['tracknum']."</td></tr>";
}
print "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: You should tell us, what your problem is.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that part.

Comment: excel does not work with tables as far as I know. Simply create a CSV file and separate the data with comma's. You can open a csv file in excel.

Comment: @John actually it does. basic html like tables works fine in excel, you just get a message saying the file doesn't look like it is in the right format but click ok and it works.

Comment: excel will accept html tables as input, but you'd be better off using PHPExcel to generate a NATIVE excel file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PHPexcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) works great for exporting data to an actual Excel document.

It appears you are just generating an HTML table with your result.. which isn't exactly Excel format.

Answer (score 1):

You should take the same code, and instead of printing `<tr>` lines with it, send it to [fputcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php).  Use the standard output as the file handle.  You need to set proper html headers for the output to be sent as a csv, along the lines of this post: [force file download](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6493794/1004027).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look a this class. It is able to solve the problem.

https://github.com/GSTVAC/HtmlExcel

```
$xls = new HtmlExcel();
$xls->addSheet("Names", $names);
$xls->headers();
echo $xls->buildFile();
```