# Remove empty lines from CSV Export in PHP

Tags: php, csv, export

I am using this Function I found here on stackoverflow

[How to create and download a csv file from php script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16251625/how-to-create-and-download-a-csv-file-from-php-script)

```php
function array_to_csv_download($array, $filename = "export.csv", $delimiter=";") {
    $f = fopen('php://output', 'w');

    foreach ($array as $line) {
        fputcsv($f, $line, $delimiter);
    }

    header('Content-Type: application/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachement; filename="'.$filename.'";');
}
```

The Problem is in the export file i have now 4 extra empty lines.

How i can fix this function to prevent these extra lines.

```
Array ( 

[0] => Array ( [start] => 001-F15:B2:1-F [dest] => 002-F15:B2:5-Y [rres_1] => 100 [rres_2] => 100 [rres_3] => 100 [runit_1] => 0 [runit_2] => 0 [runit_3] => 0 [runit_4] => 0 [runit_5] => 0 [runit_6] => 0 [worker] => 0 [duration] => 12 ) 

[1] => Array ( [start] => 001-F15:B2:1-F [dest] => 005-F15:A5:3-M [rres_1] => 0 [rres_2] => 0 [rres_3] => 0 [runit_1] => 100 [runit_2] => 100 [runit_3] => 100 [runit_4] => 0 [runit_5] => 0 [runit_6] => 0 [worker] => 0 [duration] => 12 ) 

[2] => Array ( [start] => 006-F15:E4:2-Y [dest] => 004-F15:A5:1-Y [rres_1] => 0 [rres_2] => 0 [rres_3] => 0 [runit_1] => 0 [runit_2] => 0 [runit_3] => 0 [runit_4] => 100 [runit_5] => 100 [runit_6] => 100 [worker] => 100 [duration] => 12 ) 
)
```

This lines are printed out in the `export.csv` correctly

now the complete code:

```
function array_to_csv_download($array, $filename = "export.csv", $delimiter=";") {
    header('Content-Type: application/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachement; filename="'.$filename.'";');

    // open the "output" stream
    // see http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php#refsect2-wrappers.php-unknown-unknown-unknown-descriptioq
    $f = fopen('php://output', 'w');

    foreach ($array as $line) {
        fputcsv($f, $line, $delimiter);
    }
}   
$sql='SELECT p1.planet_name AS start, p2.planet_name AS dest, rres_1, rres_2, rres_3, runit_1, runit_2, runit_3, runit_4, runit_5, runit_6, worker, duration FROM traderoute tr 
        INNER JOIN planets p1 ON p1.planet_id=tr.start_planet
        INNER JOIN planets p2 ON p2.planet_id=tr.dest_planet
        WHERE player_id='.$game->player['user_id'];
$export=$db->queryrowset($sql); 
array_to_csv_download($export);
die();
```

Comment: Are these extra lines at the beginning, at the end, scattered among the other lines?

Comment: If they're at the beginning, is there anything in your code prior to calling this function that outputs anything? echo or print statements, or blank lines outside of PHP tags? Seeing that the first few entries in your array contains data increases the likelihood of this being the cause

Comment: no only empty lines inside the PHP TAG but i removed them and get the same trouble.

Answer (score 2):

I needed to clean the lines after the closing PHP `?>` tag in the included PHP files. Then the empty lines in the csv file were gone.

Answer (score -1):

Try checking for a blank line like this:

```
foreach ($array as $line) {
   if(trim($line)!="")
   {
      fputcsv($f, $line, $delimiter);
   }
}
```

Comment: Surely `if(!empty(trim($line))) {...}` would cover more possibilities and be cleaner

Comment: PHP Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context on Line 31 and Line 31 = if(!empty(trim($line)))

Comment: i changed now to `code foreach ($array as $line) {
 
 $line=trim($line);
 
    if(!empty($line))
    {
    fputcsv($f, $line, $delimiter);
    } ` now my export file is empty

Comment: Try if(trim($line)!="")

Comment: output now is empty i get the array data from SQL database, i post now my array in the original post

Comment: I'm thinking that because the blank lines come at the beginning that maybe you are sending some output before the CSV is written.  Please include all of your code.