# PHP Mysql - show leave record in each month and leave type wise

Tags: php, mysql

My query

```
SELECT u.id
     , u.name
     , u.user_type
     , e.*
     , e.emp_id as employeeid
     , l.id
     , l.emp_id
     , l.from_date
     , l.no_days_leave
     , l.leave_type
     , l.status  
  FROM `emp_leaves` e
  JOIN `users` u 
    ON u.id = e.emp_id 
  LEFT 
  JOIN `leave_application` l 
    ON l.emp_id = e.emp_id 
 ORDER 
    BY employeeid ASC
```

Tables
Emp_leaves

```
emp_id  cl  sl  pl  total_leave
1   101     2   4   -2  4
2   106     5   7   4   16
3   107     5   7   10  22
```

in `Leave Application` table Who apply leave

```
emp_id  from_date  to_date  no_days_leave  leave_type
```

In `user` table only get employee name from id`enter code here`

I want export excel file and array like [this](http://fun2shh.com/test.png)

Comment: Please show us your Efforts...!

Answer (score 0):

The best way will be to write a script to loop over your records and create csv file from them.

See this similar answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16251849/1384300

Later by accessing this script you will be able to save it as csv, and csv is a file format supported by excel so you will be able to process it there and save in whatever format you like.

Comment: My query :  `$excel_query = "SELECT u.id,u.name,u.user_type,e.*,e.emp_id as employeeid,l.id,l.emp_id,l.from_date,l.no_days_leave,
    l.leave_type,l.status as mystatus FROM `emp_leaves` 
    AS e INNER JOIN `users` AS u ON u.id = e.emp_id 
    LEFT JOIN `leave_application` AS l ON l.emp_id = e.emp_id 
    WHERE l.status LIKE 'Approved'";`