# Basic PHP form to convert this information into a table format

Tags: php

So I am a novice , 0 clue where to start, but what I really would like is a small piece of script of possible to allow me to enter the following code into a form, then click generate and that information be displayed into a table from which I can download as a CSV.

So from the example, the B017  / Size / Colour

```
{"B017N0IXH6":["4X-Large","Schwarz"],"B017N0JF1Y":["4X-Large","Royalblau"],"B017N0K7HK":["X-Large","Himmelblau"],"B017N0JWVM":["Medium","Khaki"],"B017N0J5H8":["3X-Large","Gelb"],"B017N0KR2A":["4X-Large","Grau Meliert"],"B017N0IWAO":["3X-Large","Schwarz"],"B017N0KMT8":["Large","Grau Meliert"],"B017N0J2XU":["X-Large","Gelb"],"B017N0KGOE":["XX-Large","Oliv"],"B017N0J0SM":["Medium","Gelb"],"B017N0KNS8":["X-Large","Grau Meliert"],"B017N0JSFC":["3X-Large","Weiß"],"B017N0KHW0":["3X-Large","Oliv"],"B017N0JXW0":["Large","Khaki"],"B017N0JR6W":["XX-Large","Weiß"],"B017N0ITZC":["X-Large","Schwarz"],"B017N0KKW2":["Small","Grau Meliert"],"B017N0KEXM":["Large","Oliv"],"B017N0JVVS":["Small","Khaki"],"B017N0J1R2":["Large","Gelb"],"B017N0J6LI":["4X-Large","Gelb"],"B017N0JYYM":["X-Large","Khaki"],"B017N0ISWG":["Large","Schwarz"],"B017N0KOVY":["XX-Large","Grau Meliert"],"B017N0JBSQ":["X-Large","Royalblau"],"B017N0J8FC":["Small","Royalblau"],"B017N0IV5K":["XX-Large","Schwarz"],"B017N0J4IS":["XX-Large","Gelb"],"B017N0IYDO":["5X-Large","Schwarz"],"B017N0KFT0":["X-Large","Oliv"],"B017N0K8J2":["XX-Large","Himmelblau"],"B017N0JOT2":["Large","Weiß"],"B017N0IQQ4":["Small","Schwarz"],"B017N0KCWU":["Small","Oliv"],"B017N0K4EQ":["Small","Himmelblau"],"B017N0J7IU":["5X-Large","Gelb"],"B017N0K2ES":["4X-Large","Khaki"],"B017N0JPZK":["X-Large","Weiß"],"B017N0KLZI":["Medium","Grau Meliert"],"B017N0KJU0":["5X-Large","Oliv"],"B017N0K5F4":["Medium","Himmelblau"],"B017N0K19Y":["3X-Large","Khaki"],"B017N0JIQ6":["5X-Large","Royalblau"],"B017N0J9MY":["Medium","Royalblau"],"B017N0KBSK":["5X-Large","Himmelblau"],"B017N0KSA6":["5X-Large","Grau Meliert"],"B017N0K6HG":["Large","Himmelblau"],"B017N0JE10":["3X-Large","Royalblau"],"B017N0JNRK":["Medium","Weiß"],"B017N0K9IW":["3X-Large","Himmelblau"],"B017N0KDUQ":["Medium","Oliv"],"B017N0JUTG":["5X-Large","Weiß"],"B017N0KPYA":["3X-Large","Grau Meliert"],"B017N0K00O":["XX-Large","Khaki"],"B017N0JTQK":["4X-Large","Weiß"],"B017N0KIYC":["4X-Large","Oliv"],"B017N0JCYY":["XX-Large","Royalblau"],"B017N0K3EM":["5X-Large","Khaki"],"B017N0JMGM":["Small","Weiß"],"B017N0JANW":["Large","Royalblau"],"B017N0IRR2":["Medium","Schwarz"],"B017N0IZJC":["Small","Gelb"],"B017N0KAO0":["4X-Large","Himmelblau"]}
```

Comment: Are you asking for a finished product? Or actually trying to learn programming? Stack Overflow (Q&A) doesn't accept "questions" asking for finished pieces of software. This would certainly not be "a small piece of script".

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

All I can say is, create a workflow that you already have "actually". I would focus on the question "0 clue where to start"!

1. Create a simple form that takes the JSON array (your's doesn't look like JSON)
2. Take that JSON either save it on the server or you can simply process it on the go. (make sure to add appropriate filters to verify if the input is actually a sensible input and not the garbage to break the code.)
3. Next step will be easier, take the JSON array, perform foreach(array as entities)... and place in the table dynamically.
4. For CSV file processing.. SEARCH is what I can say... anyways you can take reference of following [How to create and download a csv file from php script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16251625/how-to-create-and-download-a-csv-file-from-php-script)

TADA ... you are done. If you want others to create the program for you, I am sorry, nobody will do that.

Just follow the steps above and you should be fine.

Enjoy coding..!! :)