# Trying to export specific SQL data with leading 0 using excel mime

Tags: php, phpexcel

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQF5J.png)[This is the output]
Trying to export SQL data as excel file by looping the array but failed to export the leading 0 of data.

I had tried to place single quote in the implode but still not working

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
$user_query = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
//echo $user_query;
// Write data to file
$flag = false;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($user_query)) {
    if (!$flag) {
        // display field/column names as first row
        echo implode("\t", array_keys($row)) . "\r\n";
        $flag = true;
    }
        echo implode("\t", =array_values($row)) . "\r\n";

}
```

> Expect to implode with "\t'" with the single quote but still failed to
>   export the leading 0

Comment: could you show `$row` output? What you have in `$row`

Comment: Stop the messing around with `implode`, and use `fputcsv` to begin with. (For an example how to use the latter for a direct download, instead of writing to an actual file, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/16251849/10283047)

Comment: @misorude I don't think CSV is expected. He's using XLS headers.

Comment: @BramVerstraten _“He's using XLS headers”_ - yeah, but the actual data format is still quite CSV-like. You’re not limited to creating “classic” CSV data with that function, it can take any character for delimiter and enclosure. (It doesn’t wrap values with a leading 0 into quotes though - maybe I’d just use a quick `array_walk` for that.)

Comment: show the content of `array_values($row)` or one generated line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `implode` like this so that each value is quoted in single quotes:

```
echo "'".implode("'\t'", array_values($row)) . "'\r\n";
```

---

UPDATE

Quoting only fields with a leading zero:

```
echo implode("\t", array_map('leadZero', $row))."\r\n";

function leadZero($element)
{
  return substr(trim($element),0,1) === "0" ? "'".$element."'" : $element;
}
```

Comment: Hi your code works but not the way I expected. Is there anyway I can target only the data with leading 0 to place the single quote in it?

Comment: The field with leading 0 remain but I get this message "  Uninitialized string offset: 0 "

Comment: Okay, change the string offset operator `{}` with `substr()`