# Laravel download query results as CSV

Tags: php, html, laravel, download

I am trying to download a query as CSV and face currently two issues:

1. A file is created in the public folder. It contains the query data. That is really bad, because it should not exist in the public folder.
2. A file is also downloaded, but the downloaded file is empty.

Here is the function:

```
public function get_chatmessages(Request $data) {

    try {  
        if ($data->chat_to_user) {              
            $result = DB::connection('mysql_live')->table('user_chatmessages')
                ->where(function($query) use($data) {
                    $query->where('from_user', $data->chat_from_user)->where('to_user', $data->chat_to_user);
                })->orWhere(function($query) use($data) {
                    $query->where('to_user', $data->chat_from_user)->where('from_user', $data->chat_to_user);
                })->orderBy('date_added', 'asc')->get();
        } else {
            $result = DB::connection('mysql_live')->table('user_chatmessages')
            ->where('from_user', $data->chat_from_user)
            ->orWhere('to_user', $data->chat_from_user)
            ->orderBy('date_added', 'asc')
            ->get();
        }

        //\Log::info($data);
        //\Log::info($result);

        $headers = array(
            "Content-type" => "text/csv",
            "Content-Disposition" => "attachment; filename=file.csv",
            "Pragma" => "no-cache",
            "Cache-Control" => "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0",
            "Expires" => "0"
        );

        $columns = array('from_user', 'to_user', 'message', 'date_added');
        $callback = function() use ($result, $columns) {
            $file = fopen('output_chat.csv', 'w');
            fputcsv($file, $columns);

            foreach($result as $res) {
                fputcsv($file, array($res->from_user, $res->to_user, $res->message, $res->date_added));
            }
            fclose($file);
        };

        //return response()->download('output_chat.csv', 'DL_output_chat.csv', $headers);
        //return response()->make($callback, 200, $headers);
        return response()->stream($callback, 200, $headers);  

    } catch (\Exception $e) {  
        return redirect('home')->with('error', $e->getMessage());  
    } 

    return redirect('home')->with('error', 'Etwas ist schief gelaufen');  
}
```

Comment: Try renaming that line `$file = fopen('output_chat.csv', 'w');` to `$file = fopen('php://output', 'w');`

Comment: Instead of opening an actual file, write to the PHP output buffer directly - see last part (“Update”) of https://stackoverflow.com/a/16251849/10283047

Comment: Yeah it worked. The original data is deleted automatically after the DL? I am not very familiar with php output buffer. Is it secure or do I have to delete something manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made little changes in your snippet regarding `php://output`

```
$headers = [
    "Content-type"        => "text/csv",
    "Content-Disposition" => "attachment; filename=output_chat.csv", // <- name of file
    "Pragma"              => "no-cache",
    "Cache-Control"       => "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0",
    "Expires"             => "0",
];
$columns  = ['from_user', 'to_user', 'message', 'date_added'];
$callback = function () use ($result, $columns) {
    $file = fopen('php://output', 'w'); //<-here. name of file is written in headers
    fputcsv($file, $columns);
    foreach ($result as $res) {
        fputcsv($file, [$res->from_user, $res->to_user, $res->message, $res->date_added]);
    }
    fclose($file);
};
```

Comment: Yeah it worked. The original data is deleted automatically after the DL? I am not very familiar with php output buffer. Is it secure or do I have to delete something manually?

Comment: for security use storage folder, laravel won't give access to that folder anyway. But in code, you can(of course you want that). The public folder is not secure because can access via URL.

Comment: But we use now the output buffer. Where is its location? So instead of output buffer I should write to storage?

Comment: You want to store it internally, not to give it to download to end-user, right?

Comment: I dont want to store. I want to download it and thats it. There should be no trace of the file on the server.

Comment: Its possible that the output buffer is what I need, I am just trying to understand whether it creates somewhere on the server the file contents and whether I need to clean the output buffer after the download.

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-uploaddownload-files-with-s3 Follow these steps.

Answer (score 0):

For Laravel, there are many packages which provide us such implementations. 
And for you to create download `csv` file with your database records you can use [Laravel Excel](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/2.1/export/export.html) package.

This package has many useful features. try to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can decide where you save files - you can do this using Laravel's Storage facade.

```
private function pathToPrivateStorage()
{
    return '/private/CSVs';
}

Storage::put($this->pathToPrivateStorage, $YOURCSVFILE);
```

You can read more about storage [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem).

Answer (score 0):

Try `$file = fopen('php://output', 'w');` in place of `$file = fopen('output_chat.csv', 'w');`