# Return laravel response as csv instead of json

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I know that any array response will be converted to json in laravel by default, but i was wondering if there is a way to return the response as csv without installing any third-party library.

I need to make one controller action returns a csv instead of JSON.

Thanx for your advice,

Comment: It isn't clear if you mean always return CSV, or for a particular method.  Laravel is just PHP - generate your CSV with `fputcsv()` as you normally would, echo the right Content-Type header, and echo the CSV.  There are many examples here, here's a good one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16251625/how-to-create-and-download-a-csv-file-from-php-script

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that without writing a lot of code.

Take a look at [this code](https://github.com/neoxia/laravel-csv-response/blob/master/src/Neoxia/Routing/ResponseFactory.php) which is the minimum you will have to do to achieve it.

Or just install the package and enjoy.