# Generate/Download of CSV throws a Connection error PHP

Tags: php, csv

So the process that I have goes like this. A user can pick a date range to view the data that he wants/needs. A Download is then available if he wants to download the file.

When doing a wide range the page throws off a connection error.

Firefox - The connection was reset

Chrome - No Data Received

The code that I use to generate the CSV is

```
<?php
$res = // the array generated by a mysql query
$text=strtotime("Now");
$filesave=fopen('Downloads/CallLogs'.$text.'.csv','w');
foreach ($res as $display)
{    
fputcsv($filesave,$display);
} 

//Force download the file. you can correct me if this is the improper way of doing it :)

header('Content-Type: application/download');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="CallLogs'.$text.'.csv"');
$fp = fopen("Downloads/CallLogs".$text.".csv", "r");
fpassthru($fp);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: This question seems like the right way to create the csv file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217424/create-a-csv-file-for-a-user-in-php

Comment: Try using `php://output` as your filename, and executing the fputcsv() loop after your headers rather than writing to disk first and then using passthru... has the added benefit of not leaving a file cluttering up the filesystem, and of allowing multiple concurrent requests without worrying about strtotime("Now") returning the exact same values

Comment: the first code was the original code I used and it will only let me download 3 days worth of data. Talking about 50K rows and it doesnt work

Comment: Then check for timeout problems

Comment: As @MarkBaker points out, you are probably running into timeouts or other resource limits.

Comment: got that thanks.. will check this info out..