# export data to csv from php

Tags: php, csv

I'm using this code as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6493794/725306).

```
$file = date('dmY-His');
header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=visitors-$file.csv");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
$sql = "select id, ip, server, time, date from visitors";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
$data = array();
$data[] = array('id', 'ip', 'server', 'time', 'date');
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    $data[] = array_values($row);
}

$output = fopen("php://output", "w");
foreach ($data as $val) {
    fputcsv($output, $val);
}
fclose($output);
```

First of all, this program in not working on my `localhost` but works fine on `server`. Why?
Second, the data I'm getting contains double entries, i.e.,

```
+----+----+---------+---------+-----------+
| id | ip | server  | time    | date      |
+----+----+---------+---------+-----------+
| 1  | 1  | :::1    | :::1    | server1   | server1  | 10:00:00 am | 12-12-2012 |
+----+----+---------+---------+-----------+----------+-------------+------------+
| 2  | 2  | :::2    | :::2    | server2   | server2  | 10:15:00 am | 13-12-2012 |
+----+----+---------+---------+-----------+----------+-------------+------------+
```

Comment: Enable error reporting and see if outputs any error messages. `doesn't work` alone isn't going to be useful if you want accurate answers.

Comment: What does it act on your localhost?

Comment: it just gives me a php file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `mysql_fetch_array()` to `mysql_fetch_assoc()`. `mysql_fetch_array()` fetches both a numeric and associative array of the database results.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
```

to

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
```

Comment: I don't know what the *real* issue is but the OP said *not working on my localhost but works fine on server*