# Add parameters to POST data and submit

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Is it possible to add parameters to your php $_POST data through javascript before submitting the form without making individual hidden input tags?

I have a page that uses ajax (non-jQuery) which parses the innerText of `<td>` elements and sends them to a php page for processing.

I'm now going to make a .csv file from that data (via the php page) and I can no longer do that via ajax.  Therefore, I have to submit the whole form and leave the page.  When doing this, I don't know how to add parameters to the $_POST data like I did with ajax.  When the form is submitted, it only processes the input tags and I can't add my custom data like I did with the ajax call.

Thanks!

EDIT:  Ajax code as requested by Matthew

```
function generateReport(saveReport)
{   
    xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
    var params = [];

    if(saveReport !== undefined)
    {
        params.push("reportName=" + document.myForm.reportName.value);
    }

    if (xmlHttp==null)
    {
      alert ("Browser does not support HTTP Request");
      return;
    } 

    var cols = document.myForm.colsUsedSel;

    if(cols.options.length == 0)
    {
        alert("Please choose columns to view in the report.");
        return;
    }

    //Loop through display columns
    for(var i = 0; i < cols.options.length; i++)
    {
        params.push("displayCols[]=" + cols.options[i].value);
    }

    //Loop through <tr>'s of "where clause" table
    var trList = document.getElementById("clauseTable").childNodes;

    for(var x = 0; x < trList.length; x++)
    {
        var tdList = trList[x].childNodes;

        for(var y = 0; y < tdList.length; y++)
        {
            var tdType = tdList[y].getAttribute("class");

            //Check if there is a class for this <td>
            if(!!tdType)
                params.push(tdType + "=" + encodeURIComponent(tdList[y].innerText));            
        }
    }


    //Loop through <tr>'s of "order by" table
    var trList = document.getElementById("orderByTable").childNodes;

    for(var x = 0; x < trList.length; x++)
    {
        var tdList = trList[x].childNodes;

        for(var y = 0; y < tdList.length; y++)
        {
            var tdType = tdList[y].getAttribute("class");

            //Check if there is a class for this <td>
            if(!!tdType)
                params.push(tdType + "=" + encodeURIComponent(tdList[y].innerText));            
        }
    }

    if(document.myForm.generateCSV.checked)
        params.push("generateCSV=1");
    else
        params.push("generateCSV=0");

    params.push("sid="+Math.random());
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange= stateChangedGenerate;
    xmlHttp.open("POST","reportBuilderDB.php",true);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlHttp.send(params.join("&"));
}
```

Comment: You can submit a form w/o leaving a page. Set the `action=''` and attack an `onSubmit` handler. Inside the `onSubmit(event)` handler, calling `event.preventDefault` will stop the page from reloading.

Comment: Thanks Matthew, but my issue is more with getting the data to the other page.  I have to do a full submit because I'm returning non-text headers and from what I've read, ajax won't make the file pop up.

`header('Content-Type: application/csv');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'";');`

Comment: Can you show us your ajax implementation code?

Comment: Edited my original post

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713058/sending-post-data-with-a-xmlhttprequest

Comment: I need to submit the form though.  When I try to do it with my ajax call, it just returns a comma list of my data instead of a csv file (with "Save As" prompt).  See example here of what I'm trying to do on php side:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217424/create-a-csv-file-for-a-user-in-php