# How to remove html tags before export to csv using php?

Tags: php

I'm trying to export records to csv file after fetch from `Mysql` using `php`. I'm following this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217424/create-a-csv-file-for-a-user-in-php) instructions and its working fine for me.

```
function array2csv(array &$array)
{
   if (count($array) == 0) {
     return null;
   }
   ob_start();
   $df = fopen("php://output", 'w');
   fputcsv($df, array_keys(reset($array)));
   foreach ($array as $row) {
      fputcsv($df, $row);
   }
   fclose($df);
   return ob_get_clean();
}

function download_send_headers($filename) {
    header("Content-Type: text/csv");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename={$filename}");
    // Disable caching
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1
    header("Pragma: no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0
    header("Expires: 0"); // Proxies
}
download_send_headers("data_export_" . date("Y-m-d") . ".csv");
echo array2csv($s);
die();
```

But problem is that this function is also adding html materials (`Header Content like title and meta title etc`) as well as records, so can anyone guide me how can i prevent to add header content for csv file. I will appreciate if someone guide me.

[image]

Comment: You shouldn't really be looking to remove the HTML from the output, you should really be working out a way not to add it in the first place if it's not wanted. How to do that? We don't know with what we know about your project.

Comment: @JonStirling Yes I want to remove HTML from the layout, can you kindly guide me how can do that?

Answer (score 2):

I have written `ob_get_clean();` at place where you have written `ob_start();` and it is solved.
I found that cleaning before the output to CSV will insert a clean data and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can changes you function like this:

```
function array2csv(array &$array)
{
   if (count($array) == 0) {
     return null;
   }
   ob_start();
   $df = fopen("php://output", 'w');
   fputcsv($df, array_keys(reset($array)));
   foreach ($array as $row) {
      $data = strip_tags($row); // strip html tags here
      if(!empty($data)){
      fputcsv($df, $data);
      }
   }
   fclose($df);
   return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by OP?

Comment: I think that Mr. Developer will find that his PHP file contains the HTML that's causing the problem. He already has Attachment disposition, so it would all be bang on if the PHP file only had PHP in it.

Comment: @Ali OP = Original Poster

Comment: Dropped previous comment as I hadn't read the code properly (and didn't really expect strip_tags to drop the doctype block). So, apologies for that, BUT, even if this does work, it's imo, the wrong place to do it.

Comment: @MarkRabjohn Yes exactly i'm facing HTML problem