# jQuery download a csv file with link onclick

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, csv

I'm trying to download a CSV file using jquery button onclick. I have an `<a>` tag with id `export` where I want it to point to the download link where I can download the CSV file that I just created.

```
// Using this jquery to send my sql query to server-side-CSV
$('#export').on('click', function() {
  var sqlsend = dataTable.ajax.json().sql;
  $.post('server-side-CSV.php', 'val=' + sqlsend, function(request){
    //code should go here
  });
});
```

And here's my php code where I'm creating a CSV file

```
// This is my server-side-CSV file. It's creating a csv file to     downloaded
<?php
require("connection.php");
$sql = $_POST['val'];
.
.more code
.

// loop over the rows, outputting them
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rows)) fputcsv($output, $row);
fclose($output);
exit;
?>
```

What can I do to download the CSV file?

EDIT:
Finally figure out the answer,

```
$('#export').on('click', function() {
  var sqlsend = dataTable.ajax.json().sql;
  window.location.href="server-side-CSV.php?val="+sqlsend;
});
```

Comment: Either use a form, or open a pop-up, or use [data URIs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665115/create-a-file-in-memory-for-user-to-download-not-through-server)

Comment: If I'm using the URI then how would I be able to send the 'sqlsend' variable to my php file? I'm sorry, pretty new to all this.

Comment: Is your `request` the file to be downloaded ?

Comment: alert(request) gives me all the data which needs to be downloaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `$.post`, send the browser to download location:

```
document.location.href = 'server-side-CSV.php?val='+sqlsend;
```

You need to add headers before the loop.

```
header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217424/create-a-csv-file-for-a-user-in-php).

Comment: Yes I already have all these headers. Stackoverflow didn't let me add all the code.

Comment: I recommend to check whether  your server-side-CSV.php file works with some SQL hardcoded into it. Call it directly from browser.

Comment: Yes it's working perfectly fine when I pass my own SQL query. When I'm passing the sql query, function(request), this 'request' variable contains all the data but not showing any download popup.

Comment: Edited my answer.